# nvarchar to date/datetime conversion failing when using sqlconnection but not in SSMS

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sqlconnection

Is there a difference between running a query with sqlconnection in .NET and running the exact same command in SSMS on the same data? I'm getting different results.

To reproduce in .NET, I have two tables in SQL Server. I create the two tables and then run a bulk import from a CSV. I then use select to insert certain columns into the second table. It works fine in SSMS, but is telling me there is a type mismatch when running in an application. Any ideas here? My queries are below:

**Table 1(temp)**

```
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[GLAnalysisTemp]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[GLAnalysisTemp];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GLAnalysisTemp] (
    [P_CATEGORY] [nvarchar] (max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_SOURCE] [nvarchar] (max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_PERIOD_NAME][nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_BF] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [P_COST_CENTER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    [P_CURRENCY] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_FROM_NAT_ACCOUNT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_TO_NAT_ACCOUNT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_ACTIVITY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_PROJECT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [P_FERC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [CREATION_DATE] [Date]  ,
    [SERVICE_TYPE_CODE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , 
    [TASK_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [TASK_NUMBER] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [QUERY_PART] [nvarchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [LEDGER_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [JOURNAL_DATE] [Date]  ,
    [POSTED_DATE] [Date]  ,
    [JV_HEADER_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [JV_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [JE_CATEGORY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [JE_SOURCE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,    
    [BATCH_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PERIOD_NAME] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [COMPANY_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BF_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CC_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACC_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,   
    [ACTIVITY_NUMBER][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PROJ_NUMBER] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FERC_NUMBER] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [COMPANY_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BF_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CC_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACC_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACTIVITY_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PROJ_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FERC_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_CR] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_DR] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_EN_CR][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_EN_DR] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [NETCHANGE] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EXTCOST] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CREATED_BY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CURRENCY_CONVERSION_RATE][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [TRANSACTION_QUANTITY][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CURRENCY_CONVERSION_DATE][Date]  ,
    [SUBINVENTORY_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ENT_CUR] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_STRING] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [JV_LINE_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EVENT_TYPE_CODE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SLA_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [AE_LINE_NUM] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_DATE][DATETIME]  ,
    [CUSTOMER_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SUPPLIER_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CUSTOMER_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SUPPLIER_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [INV_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PROJECT_NUMBER][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ASSET_NUMBER] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [PO_NUMBER] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [ITEM_NUMBER][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [HEADER_ID][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [LINE_ID] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ID_NUM] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_SL_LINK_ID][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [INVOICE_DATE] [Date]  ,
    [PART_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PART_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [TRANSACTION_REFERENCE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [TRANSCATION_TYPE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ITEM_CLASS] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ITEM_CLASS_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ITEM_CATEGORY_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SUBINVENTORY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [LOCATOR_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [UNIT_COST] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BUR_COST] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FINANCIAL_CATEGORY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GROUP_ID] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [WAREHOUSE_CODE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [RECEIPT_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CHECK_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [POSTED_BY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BATCH_STATUS] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [COMMENTS_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PO_LINE_NUM] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [REC_LINE_NUM][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PROJECT_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EXPENDITURE_TYPE_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EXP_ORG] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EVENT_TYPE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FA_LOCATION] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CATEGORY_TYPE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CATEGORY_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CATEGORY_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACCOUNTING_CLASS_CODE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ORI_LAB_ACC] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FERC_LAB][nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FERC_NON_LAB] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [DES_LAB_ACC] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [REMOVAL] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SALVAGE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BUSS_FN] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [RAW_COST] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [TRX_SOURCE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EID] [Date] ,
    [SOURCE_MODULE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EIQ] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PS] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [USER_EXP_BATCH] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EXP_COMMENTS] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [F_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [P_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SREF] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BF] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PRO] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FERC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
);
GO
```

**Table 2**

```
USE [OMData]
GO
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[GLAnalysis]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[GLAnalysis];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GLAnalysis] (
    [P_PERIOD_NAME][nvarchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
    [P_BF] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [P_COST_CENTER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [P_CURRENCY] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [P_FROM_NAT_ACCOUNT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [P_TO_NAT_ACCOUNT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [P_ACTIVITY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [P_PROJECT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [P_FERC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [CREATION_DATE] [DATE],
    [TASK_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [TASK_NUMBER] [nvarchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [JOURNAL_DATE]  [DATE],
    [POSTED_DATE] [DATE],
    [JV_HEADER_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [JV_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  ,
    [JE_CATEGORY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [JE_SOURCE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,    
    [BATCH_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PERIOD_NAME]  [nvarchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ,
    [COMPANY_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BF_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CC_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACC_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,   
    [ACTIVITY_NUMBER] [INTEGER] ,
    [PROJ_NUMBER] [INTEGER] ,
    [FERC_NUMBER] [INTEGER] ,
    [COMPANY_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BF_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CC_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACC_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACTIVITY_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PROJ_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FERC_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_EN_CR] [DECIMAL] ,
    [GL_EN_DR] [DECIMAL] ,
    [NETCHANGE] [DECIMAL] ,
    [CREATED_BY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [TRANSACTION_QUANTITY][DECIMAL] ,
    [SUBINVENTORY_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ENT_CUR] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [GL_STRING] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [JV_LINE_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EVENT_TYPE_CODE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SLA_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [AE_LINE_NUM] [FLOAT],
    [GL_DATE][DATE] ,
    [CUSTOMER_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SUPPLIER_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CUSTOMER_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SUPPLIER_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [INV_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PROJECT_NUMBER] [INTEGER] ,
    [PO_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) ,
    [ITEM_NUMBER] [FLOAT] ,
    [HEADER_ID][FLOAT] ,
    [LINE_ID] [FLOAT] ,
    [ID_NUM] [FLOAT] ,
    [GL_SL_LINK_ID] [FLOAT] ,
    [INVOICE_DATE] [DATE],
    [PART_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PART_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [TRANSACTION_REFERENCE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [TRANSCATION_TYPE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ITEM_CATEGORY_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SUBINVENTORY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [UNIT_COST] [DECIMAL] ,
    [BUR_COST] [DECIMAL] ,
    [WAREHOUSE_CODE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [RECEIPT_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CHECK_NUMBER] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [POSTED_BY] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BATCH_STATUS] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [COMMENTS_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PO_LINE_NUM] [INTEGER] ,
    [REC_LINE_NUM] [INTEGER] ,
    [PROJECT_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EXPENDITURE_TYPE_NAME] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EXP_ORG] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACCOUNTING_CLASS_CODE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ORI_LAB_ACC] [FLOAT] ,
    [FERC_LAB][INTEGER] ,
    [FERC_NON_LAB] [INTEGER] ,
    [DES_LAB_ACC] [FLOAT] ,
    [REMOVAL] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SALVAGE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [RAW_COST] [FLOAT] ,
    [TRX_SOURCE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EID] [DATE],
    [SOURCE_MODULE] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PS] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [USER_EXP_BATCH] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [EXP_COMMENTS] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [F_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [P_DESC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [SREF] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [BF] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [CC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [ACT] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [PRO] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [FERC] [nvarchar] (1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
);
GO
```

**Bulk Insert**

```
use OMData
bulk insert [OMData].[dbo].[GLAnalysisTemp] from 'R:\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVERDEV\\MSSQL\\Backup\\GLAnalysis\\GLAnalysisDay.csv' with (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a') --Dev
go
```

**Copying data into second table**

```
insert into [OMData].[dbo].[GLAnalysis] 
SELECT [P_PERIOD_NAME]
      ,[P_BF]
      ,[P_COST_CENTER]
      ,[P_CURRENCY]
      ,[P_FROM_NAT_ACCOUNT]
      ,[P_TO_NAT_ACCOUNT]
      ,[P_ACTIVITY]
      ,[P_PROJECT]
      ,[P_FERC]
      ,[CREATION_DATE]
      ,[TASK_NAME]
      ,[TASK_NUMBER]
      ,[JOURNAL_DATE]
      ,[POSTED_DATE]
      ,[JV_HEADER_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[JV_NAME]
      ,[JE_CATEGORY]
      ,[JE_SOURCE]
      ,[BATCH_NAME]
      ,[PERIOD_NAME]
      ,[COMPANY_NUMBER]
      ,[BF_NUMBER]
      ,[CC_NUMBER]
      ,[ACC_NUMBER]
      ,[ACTIVITY_NUMBER]
      ,[PROJ_NUMBER]
      ,[FERC_NUMBER]
      ,[COMPANY_DESC]
      ,[BF_DESC]
      ,[CC_DESC]
      ,[ACC_DESC]
      ,[ACTIVITY_DESC]
      ,[PROJ_DESC]
      ,[FERC_DESC]
      ,[GL_EN_CR]
      ,[GL_EN_DR]
      ,[NETCHANGE]
      ,[CREATED_BY]
      ,[TRANSACTION_QUANTITY]
      ,[SUBINVENTORY_NAME]
      ,[ENT_CUR]
      ,[GL_STRING]
      ,[JV_LINE_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[EVENT_TYPE_CODE]
      ,[SLA_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[AE_LINE_NUM]
      ,[GL_DATE]
      ,[CUSTOMER_NAME]
      ,[SUPPLIER_NAME]
      ,[CUSTOMER_NUMBER]
      ,[SUPPLIER_NUMBER]
      ,[INV_NUMBER]
      ,[PROJECT_NUMBER]
      ,[PO_NUMBER]
      ,[ITEM_NUMBER]
      ,[HEADER_ID]
      ,[LINE_ID]
      ,[ID_NUM]
      ,[GL_SL_LINK_ID]
      ,[INVOICE_DATE]
      ,[PART_NAME]
      ,[PART_NUMBER]
      ,[TRANSACTION_REFERENCE]
      ,[TRANSCATION_TYPE]
      ,[ITEM_CATEGORY_NUMBER]
      ,[SUBINVENTORY]
      ,[UNIT_COST]
      ,[BUR_COST]
      ,[WAREHOUSE_CODE]
      ,[RECEIPT_NUMBER]
      ,[CHECK_NUMBER]
      ,[POSTED_BY]
      ,[BATCH_STATUS]
      ,[COMMENTS_DESC]
      ,[PO_LINE_NUM]
      ,[REC_LINE_NUM]
      ,[PROJECT_NAME]
      ,[EXPENDITURE_TYPE_NAME]
      ,[EXP_ORG]
      ,[ACCOUNTING_CLASS_CODE]
      ,[ORI_LAB_ACC]
      ,[FERC_LAB]
      ,[FERC_NON_LAB]
      ,[DES_LAB_ACC]
      ,[REMOVAL]
      ,[SALVAGE]
      ,[RAW_COST]
      ,[TRX_SOURCE]
      ,[EID]
      ,[SOURCE_MODULE]
      ,[PS]
      ,[USER_EXP_BATCH]
      ,[EXP_COMMENTS]
      ,[F_DESC]
      ,[P_DESC]
      ,[SREF]
      ,[BF]
      ,[CC]
      ,[ACT]
      ,[PRO]
      ,[FERC]
from [OMData].[dbo].[GLAnalysisTemp]
```

The above queries work perfectly in SSMS, but not in my application. I've tried adding converts to the date time columns when inserting into the second table, it did not correct the issue. The above queries will fail during BULK INSERT, stating type mismatch for the first DATE row. If I switch everything to varchar, the bulk insert works but the insertion into the second table doesn't work. I'm using the below convert example when trying to insert into the second table, it's still giving me the type mismatch error on the first date row.

```
CONVERT(DATE, [CREATION_DATE], 103)
```

I've also tried

```
CONVERT(DATE, CAST(CREATION_DATE] AS DATE), 103)
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated! I love this community and am excited to see what brilliant answers I get, because I am fairly new to this :)

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Since you already took the debug step of trying to convert from one table to another, now use `try_convert` instead and filter out the rows where `try_convert` returns null, those will be the rows that generate errors.